# Does Java automatically parallelize recursive functions?

Tags: java, recursion, parallel-processing

I am parallelizing a recursive function and I measured poor speedup. While debugging the code, I noticed that in the sequential version all cores are working.

I have reproduced this behavior in a minimal example, and again, all my cores have a workload of about 90%. I'm using Java 8 (OpenJDK).

Is Java automatically doing parallelism without my knowledge? How is Java doing this?

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Node
{
    float value;
    ArrayList<Node> children;

    public Node()
    {
        children = new ArrayList<Node>();
    }

    public Node(float value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int count()
    {
        int count = 1;

        if (children != null)
            for (Node c : children)
                count += c.count();

        return count;
    }
}

public class ProofOfConcept {
    final static int N_NODES = 10000000;
    final static int MAX_CHILDREN = 6;

    final static Random RAND = new Random();

    static Node generateTree(int nNodes)
    {
        if (nNodes > 1)
        {
            Node result = new Node();
            int nChildren = 1 + RAND.nextInt(Math.min(MAX_CHILDREN, nNodes) - 1);
            int nNodesPerChild = (nNodes - 1) / nChildren;

            for (int i = 0; i < nChildren; ++i)
            {
                Node t = generateTree(nNodesPerChild);
                result.children.add(t);
            }

            return result;
        }
        else
            return new Node(RAND.nextFloat());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Node t = generateTree(N_NODES);
        System.out.println(t.count());
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** This is also really weird for me. I'm attaching a screenshot of htop; as you can see, we have the main process and eight threads (one for each one of my logic cores).

[image: htop]

**EDIT 2:** It seems like GC is doing its job in parallel. For those who do not understand why GC is triggered if apparently no objects are being freed, you should read the [following reference](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGMCP_4.1.0/com.ibm.cics.ts.performance.doc/topics/dfht3_jvm_gc.html):

> When a garbage collection is triggered by an allocation failure, but the garbage collection does not free enough space, the Garbage Collector expands the storage heap. During heap expansion, the Garbage Collector takes storage from the maximum amount of storage reserved for the heap (the amount specified by the -Xmx option), and adds it to the active part of the heap (which began as the size specified by the -Xms option). Heap expansion does not increase the amount of storage required for the JVM, because the maximum amount of storage specified by the -Xmx option has already been allocated to the JVM at startup. If the value of the -Xms option provides sufficient storage in the active part of the heap for your applications, the Garbage Collector does not have to carry out heap expansion at all.

Comment: Where do you see `parallel` processing here? This is single threaded program which has only `main` thread.

Comment: I don't think so. I'd more say the scheduler of the operating system is just doing it and moves the task from one core to another to another and so on.

Comment: *"all my cores have a workload of about 90%"* Something else is using them. A single-threaded Java program may jump around between all cores, but if you have 4 cores, then it would only do 25% on each.

Comment: Given that Java doesn't [optimize for tail recursion](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/272061/why-doesnt-java-have-optimization-for-tail-recursion-at-all), I would be fall-off-the-chair amazed if it automatically parallelized recursive functions.

Comment: @muradm I'm not parallelizing anything, I just think Java is doing it for me

Comment: @AKSW I don't think this is the case, I've uploaded a screenshot for clarification

Comment: @manolo, comments here as fair. additionally, in `htop`, you can use https://askubuntu.com/questions/987957/how-to-see-thread-name-in-htop to see thread names, and understand that it is not your threads consuming CPU. Another way to see threads, is `kill -3 <java_proc_pid>`, then java will dump threads to stdout. Or you can use `jconsole` to see the what JVM is doing. Otherwise you can't correlate by observation that CPU is occupied by your thread or not. OS is running 1000s of threads at the same time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, Java is not magically making your code parallel.

If you see 90% utilization on all core it's either operating system, other processes or JVM doing background work. It could be JVM using Parallel GC utilizing all cores to collect garbage.

Comment: Since the code doesn't release any objects for GC, there would be little GC going on.

Comment: @Andreas yes, but creating 10000000 Node objects will probably trigger a few  GC cycles to copy objects to old space. On JDK 8 parallel GC is still the default.

Comment: @KarolDowbecki AFAIK, GC does not run in separated threads, am I wrong?

Comment: @manolo, depends on GC implementation, but normally it has some threads.

Comment: @manolo it's not a `java.lang.Thread` but there are threads involved. On Java 8 default Parallel GC [has a concept of background GC threads](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/gctuning/parallel-collector1.htm#JSGCT-GUID-5A7866BE-59DF-44AD-B51A-274DE3F2BF59)

Comment: If the 90% * 8 CPU utilization is truly caused by GC during memory expansion, the problem can be removed/alleviated by pre-allocating enough memory for all 10 million `Node` objects by specifying `-Xms` with a large value.

Comment: @Andreas -Xms2G actually stops this behavior, thanks. However, I still do not know why GC is doing so much work... any clues @KarolDowbecki?

Comment: If you want to understand GC try collecting metrics with [Flight Recorder](https://docs.oracle.com/javacomponents/jmc-5-4/jfr-runtime-guide/run.htm#JFRUH164) and then experiment with `-Xms` and `-Xmx`. There is no way to tell just by looking at the code, it could be something like `-XX:+AlwaysPreTouch`.

Comment: @manolo See [second comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53215508/does-java-automatically-parallelize-recursive-functions/53215601?noredirect=1#comment93318878_53215601): *creating 10000000 Node objects will probably trigger a few GC cycles to **copy objects to old space***. Which happens every time memory is expanded. To see GC runs, run with `-XX:+PrintGC -XX:+PrintGCDetails`, e.g. see [Useful JVM Flags – Part 8 (GC Logging)](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/01/useful-jvm-flags-part-8-gc-logging/) for explanation.